# ExpressJS backend hanging with too much requests

Tags: ajax, node.js, jsonp, express, sequelize.js

I have an express app running with Sequelize.js as an ORM. My express app receives requests from my main Rails app, and because of the cross-domain policy, these requests are performed with getJSON.

On the client, the request is fired when the user hits a key.
Everything goes fine and express logs the queries being performed (and json being served) each time the user hits the key. Even trying to hit quickly it performs ok. But, whenever I leave the key pressed (or maybe several clients hitting the key very quickly), as it starts firing lots of requests, at some moment the server just hangs, all the requests from that point on are left pending (I see that in the Network tab of Chrome Dev Tools), and they slowly start to timeout. I have to reboot the server to make it respond again.

The server code for my request is:

```
models.Comment.findAllPublic(req.params.pId, req.params.sId, function(comments){
                var json = comments.map(function(comment){
                    var com = {};
                    ['user_id','user_avatar', 'user_slug', 'user_name', 'created_at', 'text', 'private', 'is_speaker_note'].forEach(function(key){
                        com[key]=comment[key];
                    });
                    return com;
                });

                res.json({comments: json});
        });
```

And the findAllPublic method from the Comment model (this is a Sequelize model) is:

```
findAllPublicAndMyNotes: function(current_user, presentationId, slideId, cb){
                db.query("SELECT * FROM `comments` WHERE  commentable_type='Slide' AND commentable_id=(SELECT id from `slides` where `order_in_presentation`="+slideId+" AND `presentation_id`="+presentationId+") AND (`private` IS FALSE OR (`private` IS TRUE AND `user_id`="+current_user+" AND `is_speaker_note` IS FALSE))",self.Comment).on('success', cb).on('failure',function(err){console.log(err);});
            }
```

How to avoid the server from getting stuck? Am I leaving some blocking code in the request that may slowly hang the server as new requests are made?

At first I thought it could be a problem because of the "forEach" when composing the json object from the Sequelize model, but I also tried leaving the callback for the mysql query empty, just responding empty json and it also got frozen.

Maybe it is a problem of the mysql connector? When the server gets stuck I can normally run the mysql console and perform queries on my database and it also responds, so I don't know if that's the problem.

I know I could just control the key event to prevent it from firing too many requests when the key gets pressed for a long time, but the problem seems to appear also when several clients hit the key repeatedly and concurrently.

Any thoughts? Thanks in advance for the help :D

Comment: You creating something like autosuggest?

Answer (score 2):

Two things:

1. It seems like you have some path where `res.render` is not being called. It could be that the database you're connecting to is dropping the connection to your Express server after the absurd number of requests and the callback is never fired (and there's no `database.on('close', function() { // Handle disconnect from DB, perhaps auto-restarting })` code to catch it.
2. Your client-side code should detect when an AJAX request on keypress is still pending while a new one is being started, and cancel the old one. I'm guessing `getJSON` is a jQuery method? Assuming it's jQuery's, then you need something like the following

.

```
var currKeyRequest = null;
function callOnKeyUp() {
    var searchText = $('#myInputBox').value;
    if(currKeyRequest) {
        currKeyRequest.reject();
        currKeyRequest = null;
    }
    currKeyRequest = $.getJSON('path/to/server', function(json) {
        currKeyRequest = null;
        // Use JSON code
    });
}
```

This way, you reduce the load on the client, the latency of the autocomplete functionality (but why not use the jQuery UI autocomplete if that's what you're after?), and you can save the server from some of the load as well if the keypresses are faster than handshaking with the server (possible with a good touch-typist a few hours flight away).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, it has led me to find some info that I think may be related to this issue.

What I am developing is a realtime presentation system, and as the user hits forward/back key, the slides are loaded and the user's comments on that slides are loaded too. So it's not an autocomplete :).

Thanks to your comment I have found that sequelize.js as of now, uses the node-mysql connector, where we can find this [opened issue](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql/issues/113).
Do you think it may be related? The sequelize author also says he's going to change the connector.

Comment: Apart from that, I have tried the solution for controlling pending requests in the client, and unfortunately, It seems that the object returned by the jquery's getJSON method doesn't implement reject, although it implements some other methods of a Deferred element. Any clue on this? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @scumah: Not to discredit felixge's work, but I think he's spread himself too thin. I've had to fork a library of his before because he simply didn't want to even review a patch I submitted to a relatively simple library (node-dateformat). That issue sounds like it very well could be the cause of the problem -- if it gets disconnected, it fires no events on that failure and doesn't try to reconnect. With respect to getJSON not providing the "right" object, what version of jQuery are you using? Older versions just provide ``XMLHttpRequest`` objects and you can just ``.abort()``